# Set values conditionally in Postgres UPSERT

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5, upsert

We have an *UPSERT* feature achieved through [`on conflict do set`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-insert.html#SQL-ON-CONFLICT). How can I set the values conditionally in the set statement, like

```
if(excluded.col1 is null) col1=table.col1 else col1=excluded.col1
```

We are using Postgres 9.5.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
...
SET   col1 = COALESCE(excluded.col1, table.col1)
...
```

Of course, both tables must be visible.

***If*** you are updating `table1` and that's the only change you make it's much more efficient to use a `WHERE` clause:

```
...
SET   col1 = excluded.col1
WHERE excluded.col1 IS NOT NULL
AND   excluded.col1 IS DISTINCT FROM table1.col1 -- to avoid empty updates
...
```

About the added second condition:

- [How do I (or can I) SELECT DISTINCT on multiple columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12632129/939860)